# Empty response from druid when using quantile data sketch aggregator

Tags: druid

I am trying to compute the the 95th percentile value of a metric in druid. I came across this documentation https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-quantiles.html which says that we can build sketches from raw data at query time.

I prepared this druid query

```
{
    "queryType": "timeseries",
    "intervals": [
        "2020-05-08T11:45:00.000Z/2020-05-08T11:50:00.000Z"
    ],
    "granularity": "minute",
    "dataSource": "datasource",
    "filter": {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "hostName",
        "value": "host"
    },
    "postAggregation": [
        {
            "type": "quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile",
            "name": "dim",
            "field": "dim",
            "fraction": 0.5
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting empty response from druid when I fire this query. The output is

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-05-08T11:45:00.000Z",
    "result": {

    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-05-08T11:46:00.000Z",
    "result": {

    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-05-08T11:47:00.000Z",
    "result": {

    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-05-08T11:48:00.000Z",
    "result": {

    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-05-08T11:49:00.000Z",
    "result": {

    }
  }
]
```

I verified that data is present in druid within that time range. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a `postAggregator` of type `quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile`, which you're passing the field `dim`.  That function takes a sketch and converts it to a quantile after aggregation, but it doesn't build the sketch, rather it expects the sketch as input.  You first need to create an aggregation using the function `quantilesDoublesSketch`, that's where you pass in `dim`, you can then use the sketch that results in your `postAggregator`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's looking for a working code, here's what works for me:

```
{
    "queryType": "timeseries",
    "intervals": "2022-04-17T00:00:00+00:00/2101-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "fieldName": "my_dimension",
            "name": "my_dimension_agg",
            "type": "quantilesDoublesSketch"
        }
    ],
    "postAggregations": [
        {
            "type"  : "quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile",
            "name": "median_value",
            "field"  :  {
                "type": "fieldAccess",
                 "fieldName": "my_dimension_agg"
              },
            "fraction" : 0.5
          }
    ],
    "dataSource": "my_datasource",
    "granularity": "all"
}
```

Send query using:

```
curl -X POST 'http://your-server:8082/druid/v2/?pretty' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Accept:application/json' -d @/home/directory/druid/your-query.json
```